# Unsigned Number displays different results when a zero is appended to the number

Tags: c++

Why does this program display 2 different numbers when unsigned number is chnaged from '437' to '0437' cout statement? when I put 437 the cout shows 437 but when i use '0437' it shows '287'. Why is it so?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned number = 437;
    cout<<number<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because a leading 0 turns it into an octal integer literal

Comment: how do you get rid of the annoying octal integer literal? pls

Comment: Find a different language.

Comment: Don't add a 0 at the front?

Comment: You don't get rid of octal literals.  There is no reason to write 01234 unless you want an octal literal.  If you want 1234 you just write 1234

Comment: You can explicitly set the base for your conversion as well as setting the starting `pos` for your conversion to begin, e.g. [std::stoi, std::stol, std::stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) Either will allow you to skip the leading zero.

Comment: The program i am/was writing required a user input and the user may put in a 0437 instead of 437 so may the "UnholySheep" become holy with velcro gloves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value represented by an octal literal is being printed out as decimal value on the standard output. If you want to output the octal literal value you should use the [std::oct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) stream manipulator:

```
std::cout << std::oct << number;
```

Integer values are represented by [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). They can be octal such as `0437`, decimal such as `287` or hexadecimal such as `0x11f` and as of C++14 they can be binary literals such as `0b100011111`. All of these literals represent the same value.

Comment: You can add `0b100011111` to that as the binary literal version.

Comment: That edit is *much* better! I have withdrawn my downvote.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Indeed. Updated.

Comment: @MartinBonner Appreciate the feedback. The original was indeed somewhat botched.